# eliminate global variable from recursive function

Tags: python

I wrote this very simple function to count the steps for the Collatz series to converge to 1. It is called recursively but uses a global variable which I would like to eliminate. I believe that the proper(?) way to do this is to make the variable a parameter of the function call; however, when I did this I got the value after the calls were all unwound rather than the last value. For example, if you call this function with `steps = 0; collatz(97)`, you will get `118` returned.

```
def collatz(num):
    global steps
    steps += 1
    if num == 1:
        return
    if num % 2 == 0:
        num = num / 2
    else:
        num = 3 * num + 1
    collatz(num)
    return (steps - 1)
```

With a parameter for the variable steps:

```
def collatz(num,steps):
    steps += 1
    if num == 1:
        return
    if num % 2 == 0:
        num = num / 2
    else:
        num = 3 * num + 1
    collatz(num,steps)
    return (steps - 1)
```

`collatz(97,0)` returns `0`. I know I am overlooking something but what?

Comment: 1. steps == 0 2. steps += 1 => steps == 1 3. you do something 4. return steps - 1 +> steps == 0. all works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local variable `steps` is immutable. The recursive call will not be able to magically modify or rebind it, nor has the recursive function call any access to the surrounding scope. You have to communicate recursive intermediate results via the return value. Try the following:

```
def collatz(num, steps=0):
    if num == 1:
        return steps
    if num % 2 == 0:
        num = num / 2
    else:
        num = 3 * num + 1
    return collatz(num, steps+1)

>>> collatz(97)
118
```

Comment: No parameter is needed, just return the steps below `+1`, as in my answer.

Comment: @JoeIddon That is true, but this is closer to the original logic.

Comment: Fair enough, so +1, but I prefer my method as it is cleaner :)

Comment: This address a common misconception about recursion, which is that you don't need to explicitly return the return value of the recursive call. The original approach is not the best, but this answer clearly fixes the problem in the implementation of that approach.

Comment: @JoeIddon Yours is absolutely cleaner =)

Answer (score 3):

No global needed, each function returns the steps required from that sequence onwards plus 1, where the base case (`num == 1`) returns `0`:

```
def collatz(num):
    if num == 1:
        return 0
    if num % 2 == 0:
        num = num / 2
    else:
        num = 3 * num + 1
    return collatz(num) + 1
```

e.g.

```
>>> collatz(97)
118
```